# Qr component bug in mgcv::gam?

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I tried to follow the example 7.2.6-Prediction with predict.gam
from Generalized Additive model : An introduction with R.

However, when I ran
`predict(m2)[1:5]`

It always gave the following error:

```
Error in x$qr %||% stop("lm object does not have a proper 'qr' component.\n Rank zero or should not have used lm(.., qr=FALSE).") : 
  lm object does not have a proper 'qr' component.
 Rank zero or should not have used lm(.., qr=FALSE).
```

Is there any solution to solve this? I tried to predict another GAM model, restarting R session, and still gave the same error.

Comment: I had the same problem. I forgot to library(mgcv)!